# How can I do a compare when the second is a sub select that returns multiple values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Here's my SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
   FROM OWU_Nomination as a, 
        Merchants as b WHERE a.CallFlag = 'False' 
   AND a.nominatedDate < DateAdd(hour, -24, getdate()) 
   AND a.email != (SELECT c.Email from Members as c where c.MemberID = b.MemberID)
```

The problem here is that the sub select after `a.email !=` returns multiple records. I would like to see if `a.email` is in any of the emails returned from the subselect, is this possible? Is there a Contains function or something similar that will do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I'm not sure if you want it to be in the set or not in the set.

If it must be in the set, use this clause:

```
AND a.email IN (SELECT c.Email from Members as c where c.MemberID = b.MemberID)
```

otherwise:

```
AND a.email NOT IN (SELECT c.Email from Members as c where c.MemberID = b.MemberID)
```